# Pass variables from a form in a smarty tpl to a controller on form submit

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller, prestashop-1.6

I have a form in a tpl file:

```
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('virtual_pos', 'validation', [], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post"> 
  ... 
</form>
```

On submit I would like to get all the variables from the form and pass them to the controller 'validation'.

I don't wanna use any JS. It is a payment module for a store.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution in another thread.

When the link to the controller is created you can fill the variables that you need in the empty array parameter:

```
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('virtual_pos', 'validation', ['id'=>$cart_id], true)|escape:'html'}" method="post">
```

Then in the controller you can get the data with the super global

```
$id_from_form_submit = $GET['id'];
```

If you know any other option please let me know.

Comment: $id_from_form_submit = $_GET['id'];* You missed _

Answer (score 0):

In your module create a file controllers/front/validation.php.
There you need a class:

```
class virtual_posValidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function postProcess()
    {
          /* where you get the values and validate the order */
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        /* where you set data for a last page order confirmation */
    }
}
```

Have you created this already?

Comment: I am handling this with a redirect to order-confirmation. since I am waiting for a AJAX call to return from an API. Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.$cart->id.'&id_module='.
     $this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);